# Can you explain the what the difference between this solution

Tags: java

Hi  i have solved one coding competition problem in that this
and un acceptable solution is this

```
    boolean found=true;
        int ar[]=new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //ar[i]=sc.nextInt();
            int temp=sc.nextInt();
            if(h==temp+x) {
                found=false;
            System.out.println("Yes");
                
                
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            System.out.println("NO");
            
        }
```

and accepted solution is this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //ar[i]=sc.nextInt();
            int temp=sc.nextInt();
            if(h==temp+x) {
                found=false;
                
                
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            System.out.println("NO");
            
        }else{
         System.out.println("YES");   
        }
```

I did not found any difference in that because in 1st i have assign boolean value and print and second i just assign and later print and just normally made this change and its accepted can any one explain me

Comment: If `found` equals false, your answer will print `YES`  and then `NO`. The solution only prints `NO` if `found` is false. If `found` equals true, your answer prints nothing. The solution only prints `Yes` if `found` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, if the condition `h==temp+x` matched multiple time then you will print multiple time while in second you are printing one time only. If you want above one to work you can put break condition inside the if.

For eg: temp values are `1,2,3,3,4` and `h` is `6` and `x` is `3`. You will print `yes` twice.

Possible solution:

```
boolean found=true;
    int ar[]=new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //ar[i]=sc.nextInt();
        int temp=sc.nextInt();
        if(h==temp+x) {
            found=false;
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) {
        System.out.println("NO");
        
    }
```

By the way putting `break` will make your code run faster for some cases.

Comment: Thanks i didn't notice that this will print multiple line when condition match.